# Changing content/src of image dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple animation using only HTML and CSS/CSS3.

Now i am reading a bit into CSS3 tranforms.
I am able to create this demo

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89/1/)

Now this is just a plain hover animation which rotates the image 180 degrees for a duration of 2 seconds.

Now im tring to add the `content:url` property in CSS to the `':hover'` part so that when the image flips the *source* of the image should change. However if I try this it does not work and the animation fails too.

Can this be done using only CSS & HTML or do I have to use javascript/jQuery.

[Not working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89)

CSS

```
img{
width:200px;
height:300px;
}
img:hover
{
transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);    
content:url("http://tinyurl.com/n6qyafn");
transition-duration: 3s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Comment: `content` is only applicable to pseudo-elements (like `:after`) - you can't change the `src` attribute with css alone. What you *can* do is change the `content` on hover, however: http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89/2/

Comment: I tried this method. Now the image changes but it does not apply the transition. http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89/4/

Comment: To start with, use background rather than content: http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89/5/

Comment: I checked this Fiddle. Looks good. But the image changes as soon as the div is hovered upon and then the end image is inverted which i do not want. any work around?

Comment: I'm assuming you want a flip card type effect, check out http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php

Comment: You could solve this with using a CSS-sprite instead of trying to swap out the image source. Might be simpler in the end.

Comment: @xec, The flipcard effect is exactly what i want. How do i apply it with images?

Comment: Like @3dgoo suggested, you can use background-image. Check out the source from the demo, it's using several elements for each flipcard, so you can have a separate background for the front and back. You can even use different `<img>` tags instead if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using 2 divs, a back and front and swapping them on rotate:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel {
    width: 186px;
    height: 271px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
}
.panel .front, 
.panel .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel .front {
    z-index: 900;
    background: url("http://tinyurl.com/n5d9bet");
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
.panel:hover .front {
    z-index: 900;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel .back {
    z-index: 800;
    background: url("http://tinyurl.com/n6qyafn");
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.panel:hover .back {
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DycUq/1/)**

**[Source](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php)**

### Alternative transition method

A simpler way is to use delay on transitioning the background image to halfway between the rotate transition.

**HTML**

```
<div id="card"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#card {
    background: url("http://tinyurl.com/n5d9bet");
    width: 186px;
    height: 271px;
    transition: all 1s linear, background-image 0ms 500ms linear;
}
#card:hover {
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    background: url("http://tinyurl.com/n6qyafn");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySQ89/8/)**

Comment: I found the 2 divs solution better. The alternative solution inverts the Card.